# Правильно ли построено предложение?

Tags: стилистика

"Кроме уже перечисленных прав и обязанностей директор школы в том числе 
принимает решение о награждении обучающегося".

Все ли тут верно?

Comment: Вопрос вот в чем: не выглядит ли это так, будто директор принимает и права с обязанностями?

Comment: Метка должна отражать конкретную специфику вопроса.

Comment: Почему вопрос закрыли? Очень даже конкретно поставлен вопрос. А метки можно изменить.

Comment: Вопрос вполне конкретный. А если дело только в метках, то лично мне трудно сориентироваться в них - не очень удобно. К тому же не вижу принципиального различия между меткой "стилистика" и "говорим правильно".

Comment: juki, если Вы еще раз поведете себя подобным образом, я вынуждена буду забанить Вас на форуме навсегда! Прекратите это бестолковое самоуправство!  
Администратор.

Comment: Всё смешалось в доме Облонских, или Девки спорили на даче...

Кто из вас главнее в конце-то концов?!
Если модератор круче администратора, то зачем этот модератор подписывантся Администратором?!
А если нет, то как модератор может забанить Администратора?!

Понимаю, админы дерутся - у юзеров чубы трещат, но не комильфо это, ей-богу, администрации на людях отношнгия выяснять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что да. Чисто интуитивно могу сказать, что "в том числе" запятыми тут не выделяется. Другое дело, что предложение немного громоздкое и канцелярское, но, видимо, так надо.

Answer (score 1):

Распространенное дополнение с предлогом "кроме" должно быть выделено запятой (Розенталь), так что предложение должно выглядеть так:"Кроме уже перечисленных прав и обязанностей, директор школы в том числе принимает решение о награждении обучающегося".

Comment: Обороты с союзом "кроме" не обособляются, если имеют значение включения в общий контекст предложения (здесь предлог кроме синонимичен предлогу наряду): 
Кроме небольшого столика с зеркалом в комнате стояла кровать (= Наряду с небольшим столиком с зеркалом, в комнате стояла кровать).

Answer (score 0):

"в том числе", по моему, здесь вовсе лишнее.
Есть права и обязанности (перечислены уже). Кроме них директор принимает решение о...
Как бы "мы забыли перечислить и это его право (обязанность)".

Answer (score 0):

Не верно.

Оборот с `кроме` обособляется.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_370

Использование `в том числе` не верно. Оно используется для конкретизации после этого "числа". А здесь нечего конкретизировать.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_129

Если так сделать, то правильно и есть конкретизация:

Кроме уже перечисленных прав и обязанностей, директор школы принимает решение о награждении обучающихся, в том числе и хорошистов.